# Object "name" undefined, no matter how I select it

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I can't for the life of me select this correctly? I may have the for loop wrong so please advice if that is the case:

```
    function(data, callback){
        data.champNames = {};
        for(var c in data.champId){
            val = data.champId[c];
            var surl = 'https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/'+ [val] + '?api_key=' + api_key;
            request(surl, function(err, response, body){
                if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
                    var json = JSON.parse(body);                        
                    //data.champNames.push(json[val].name);
                    console.log(json);                        
                } else {
                    console.log('Error in Champ Name');
                }
            })
            console.log(val);                
        } console.log(data);
    }
```

The  data.champNames.push(json[val].name) will not work, JSON is returned as the below in console:

```
{ id: 1, key: 'Annie', name: 'Annie', title: 'the Dark Child' }
{ id: 76,
  key: 'Nidalee',
  name: 'Nidalee',
  title: 'the Bestial Huntress' }
{ id: 15,
  key: 'Sivir',
  name: 'Sivir',
  title: 'the Battle Mistress' }
{ id: 103,
  key: 'Ahri',
  name: 'Ahri',
  title: 'the Nine-Tailed Fox' }
```

Data is a global variable used within an async waterfall.

ChampId is already in an array and is returned as:

```
  champId: [ 22, 236, 76, 21, 36, 133, 24, 103, 81, 79, 45, 15, 1, 0 ],
```

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with JSON. Note that the code won't work as you expect anyway. The `for` loop is synchronous, so `console.log(data)` will be executed **before** any of the `request` callbacks is executed. You should read [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196)

Comment: Before `console.log(val);` you are missing `;`.

Comment: @Legionar: `;` are optional.

Comment: Hey, would you mind sharing how I would change this to do as I want? I want to be able to display these on the page, along with howmany times they've played the champ. I've got the number of times already stored, I just need to now get the names.

Comment: You already gave your function a `callback` parameter, seemingly knowing of its asynchrony. So then why don't you use it?!

Comment: Hello, I may be trying to run before I can walk but I'm learning this as I go. What do you mean why I don't I use it?

Comment: *"What do you mean why I don't I use it?"* The function accepts a parameter `callback`. Why did you add it and why are you not referencing it inside the function?

Comment: Where abouts would I reference callback? As I said this is what I've written from finding bits and pieces doing similar things to what I wanted. I don't particularly know what callback even does. Sorry!

Comment: Objects do not have a push method...

Comment: Well, as you can see, copying and pasting pieces without really understanding them won't get you far. Btw, to access the name of the object from the response, you just need to do `json.name`. However, that is the least of your problems.

Comment: Who said it was copied and pasted? Non of it is, I've tried to fully understand what I can, got stuck, and came here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`data.champNames={}` is a dictionary in your case.To use `push` method you need to use an `array`. Try this:

```
data.champNames = [];
```

Or,if you want use dictionary use this:

```
data.champNames["key"]=value;
```

Updated answer:

One method is to use [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
for(var c in data.champId){
        val = data.champId[c];
        var surl = 'https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/'+ [val] + '?api_key=' + api_key;
        (function(val){
            request(surl, function(err, response, body){
            if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
                var json = JSON.parse(body);                        
                //data.champNames.push(json[val].name);
                console.log(json);                        
            } else {
                console.log('Error in Champ Name');
            }
        })(val);
        console.log(val);                
 }
```

Another solution is to use `let` keyword.

> ES6 provides the let keyword for this exact circumstance. Instead of
>   using closures, we can just use let to set a loop scope variable.

Please try this:

```
for(let c in data.champId){
        let val = data.champId[c];
        var surl = 'https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/'+ [val] + '?api_key=' + api_key;
        request(surl, function(err, response, body){
            if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
                var json = JSON.parse(body);                        
                //data.champNames.push(json[val].name);
                console.log(json);                        
            } else {
                console.log('Error in Champ Name');
            }
        })               
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I changed it to an array and used: data.champNames.push(json[c].name); however I get cannot read property of name "Undefined"

Comment: @InchHigh: This cannot work because `c` doesn't have the value you expect (`val` wouldn't either btw). See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196). You need another way to iterate and process your data asynchronously. You should look into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: How many objects do you have in json array ? For example, in your `champId` , first element is 22, and in your example JSON have only 4 elements.

Comment: @FelixKling,yes, you're right..he needs to use closures or `.bind` function.

Answer (score 1):

While accessing the object seems to be an issue, the bigger issue is actually with how you process the data. You are performing an *asynchronous* operation (`request(...)`) inside a synchronous loop (`for...in`). Because of the way JavaScript works, that means the loop will finish first before any of the `request` callbacks is executed.

The issues in your code have been covered extensively in other questions and resources, so I highly recommend to read the following before you do anything else:

- [Concurrency model and Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)
- [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

In order to solve your particular problem, you should look into [*Promises*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). We will create a new promise for each entry in the `data.champId` array. A promise is basically a placeholder for a *future* value. A promise can either *resolve* to a value or be *rejected* if there was an error. Here, each promise will be a placeholder for the response received via `request`, which is an asynchronous process. In particular, each of these promises will resolve to the `name` of the response object. Helper methods such as `Promise.all` allow us to perform an action once *multiple* promises are resolved.

```
function fetchNames(data) {
  // Promise.all returns a new promise that resolves when all promises passed to it
  // are resolved
  return Promise.all(data.champId.map(function(id) {

    var surl = 'https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion/'+ id + '?api_key=' + api_key;

    // Create a new promise for each entry in data.champId
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      request(surl, function(err, response, body){
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200){
          var result = JSON.parse(body);
          resolve(result.name); // the response is an object with a property name                    
        } else {
          reject('Unable to load entry "' + id + '"');
        }

    });
  });

}

fetchNames({champId: [ 22, 236, 76, 21, 36, 133, 24, 103, 81, 79, 45, 15, 1, 0 ]})
  .then(function(names) {
    console.log(names);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // An error occured
  });
```

Comment: This is a very beautiful explanation.

Comment: I will read all of the topics you've posted, and will also try the above code. Thankyou so much for your time. I'm going to read about Promise etc so that I also understand what you've supplied. Thanks agina!

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to do a push in an object: you declared `data.champNames = {}`, but for a push you need an array `data.champNames = [];`).

Reading the code I can assume you're trying to read the val-th element of the JSON array, not the JSON element with id == val.  If you want to get the name of the element with id==val you have to do a search inside the JSON object.

Comment: Alexandru-Ionut Mihai already provided that answer. Why repeat it?